# ElasticSearch: Java High Level API - Index doc with dynamic ID

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch (ES). Day one on the java high level API.

I understand that POST a document allows ES to auto-generate the document ID. PUT allows me to use a pre-existing ID.

From the API docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html), I am not sure how to differentiate between the two approaches when indexing a new document. I wish to use the POST approach.

Comment: You want to use the POST approach as in you don't want to specify the ID? The title says "with know ID".

Comment: tks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java API has an overloaded IndexRequest constructor. If you don't want to specify the ID, you don't have to.

```
public IndexRequest(String index, String type) {
    ...
}

public IndexRequest(String index, String type, String id) {
    ...
}
```

Presumably the former is a POST request and the latter is a PUT.